# Probability counting question combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

You must choose 9 courses from a list of 20 classes. At least one course has to be a math class, and 5 out of the 20 classes are math classes. How many possible combinations of 9 classes can the student take? I thought the answer was (5 choose 1) x (19 choose 8). Why not?

Comment: Your idea double-counts schedules with more than 1 math class.

Comment: 9, typo. So, how do I do it? Divide it by the double counted..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add up the following:

- Number of combinations with exactly $1$ math course:  $\dbinom{5}{1}\cdot\dbinom{15}{8}$
- Number of combinations with exactly $2$ math courses: $\dbinom{5}{2}\cdot\dbinom{15}{7}$
- Number of combinations with exactly $3$ math courses: $\dbinom{5}{3}\cdot\dbinom{15}{6}$
- Number of combinations with exactly $4$ math courses: $\dbinom{5}{4}\cdot\dbinom{15}{5}$
- Number of combinations with exactly $5$ math courses: $\dbinom{5}{5}\cdot\dbinom{15}{4}$

The result is $32175+64350+50050+15015+1365=162955$.

Answer (score 2):

There are $\binom{20}{9}$ possibilities if there are no restrictions. Under the restriction that **no** math class is chosen there are $\binom{15}{9}$ possibilities. Consequently there are $\binom{20}{9}-\binom{15}{9}$ possibilities under the restriction that **at least one** math class is chosen.